# Disable UITableView horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I created a `UITableView` with a small frame, like (0,0,50,50). I want to disable the horizontal scrolling but keep the vertical scrolling.

I set `self.table.bounces = NO`, but the tableview can't be vertically scrolled, either. As a result, the animation is not so perfect.

So anyone has tips?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the content size of the tableView, make sure the width of the content size is not greater than the frame size

```
self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
```

Answer (score 6):

Check if the content inset property of the table view is nonzero. If so reset it to zero.

Comment: Provide a code sample to illustrate your answer, it'll make your answer more complete and helpful.

Comment: I upvoted this because it's sort of correct, but a part of me wants to brutally downvote it.  In fact, I WANTED my table view to have non-zero content insets, so that I could give it margins without having to lay everything out all over again.  But it indeed appears that setting the content insets to non-zero forces horizontal scrolling.  Thanks, Apple!

Comment: what if I want to put margin there?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `AlwaysBounceHorizontal` property of UITableView to false as follows:

**Swift:**

```
self.tableView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
```

**Objective-C:**

```
[self.tableView setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tblViewProfile.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false // using coding
```

Or by **storyboard/xib**

> [Un tick horizontal bounce option in storyboard or xib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cG59.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you've applied `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior =` , try selecting the value  `.scrollableAxes` instead of `.automatic` or `.always`

Answer (score -1):

If you created the table view in the interface builder then there is an option check the scroll vertically and uncheck the horizontal scroll.

If you didn't then you should try create it in the interface builder and assign it to your IBOutlet

Hope it helps !

Comment: But I really don't want to use nib...
could you tell how to change it in code?

Comment: Moreover, I didn't find the property you said.
If you mean "shows Horizontal Scrollers", it just controls the indicator for scrolling.