# How to diable horizontal scrolling of uitable view?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable UITableView horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309821/disable-uitableview-horizontal-scroll)

Please can any one tell me how to disable horizontal scrolling of tableview..

Kindly help..

Comment: Don't make your content wider than your tableview :)

Comment: sorry sir but i have a table which is not of the size of the view...please help

Comment: self.tableView.contentSize =CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width,tableView_height); just search for some answer maybe [Disable UITableView horizontal scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309821/disable-uitableview-horizontal-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

If your tablecontentview width is same as your view width it will not scroll in horizontal way but if you want that your tableview should not bounce then you can disable bouncing of your tableview as

m_TableView.bounces = NO;

Comment: sorry sir but i have a table which is not of the size of the view...please help

Comment: Then how are you assigning tableview and its content frame?Can you just show how are you assigning frame?

Comment: Sir i have two table view.By scrolling one view other will be scrolled but if the first one is scrolled horizontally second should not scroll horizontally....As i have set contentOffset of both tableview ...so it is scrolling both type of scrolling.....

Comment: Nitesh your question is bit confusing.Can you please elaborate it properly?